# Limit maximum screen brightness when using auto brightness via ADB on Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra

Tags: adb, samsung, screen-brightness, samsung-galaxy-s-23

Is there any way to limit the maximum brightness on the S23 Ultra or other Samsung devices, I want to save more battery without having to use it manually. Many thanks